# ADHD in the Percy Jackson universe

Tags: percy-jackson, psychology

I've seen the films but haven't read any of the books.

1. Did Percy Jackson get treated for ADHD prior to his finding out about himself being a demigod? If so how? If not why?
2. How do Percy Jackson and the other demigods get treated for their ADHD? I don't recall Camp Half Blood having a psychiatrist or psychologist there.

Comment: also... I thought the idea was that the demigods didn't _actually_ have ADHD -- their demigod status was causing them to be misdiagnosed. Presumably, once they knew their heritage and were among other demigods it would stop being a problem?

Comment: @KutuluMike I assume that by 'it' you mean the symptoms related to the ADHD/supposed ADHD such as difficulties in concentration, executive functioning, etc. If someone has difficulties, say for example, in executive functioning and is misdiagnosed with ADHD and then later turns out to have say for example OCD, that person would still continue to have said difficulties until treated for OCD right? So if we grant Percy Jackson [doesn't have ADHD](http://bit.ly/2dX8Rnn), the fact remains that he still has symptoms and [needs treatment](http://bit.ly/1W1J5HE) right?

Comment: ... maybe. But my impression was that the symptoms were an effect of demigods trying to live in modern society; once they reached Camp Halfblood and began training/exercising the demigod-ness, the symptoms would "go away"...

Comment: @KutuluMike By "go away" did you mean "would no longer be symptoms" ? I mean Camp Half Blood much like a hunter-gatherer society may find ADH'D' advantageous (hence we can drop the latter 'D'), but there are still some aspects that may need treatment? Such as say eating or sleeping? I don't believe Camp Half Blood is 100% like hunter-gatherer and 0% like farming society

Comment: @KutuluMike But if you meant "go away" as in would be treated, well that would be like saying putting someone with ADHD in a hunter-gatherer society would lead that someone to have their ADHD treated? I don't see why that would be the case, and I don't see why anyone with ADHD would want their ADHD treated if they were in a hunter-gatherer society...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) He mentions in the first book the school counsellor telling him anger management and ADHD management strategies.

> "The school counsellor told me this was part of my ADHD, my brain misinterpreting things."
>
> <sub><sup>Lightning thief: Chapter 1</sup></sub>

2) They don't ever mention a psychiatrist at camp Half-Blood. Presumably because ADHD helps in battle so they need to be ADHD to stay alive.

Comment: Thank you Bellerophon :) So Camp Half Blood then is like a hunter-gatherer society? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_vs._farmer_hypothesis

Comment: did all the demigods just stop mortal treatment for their ADHD/ADHD symptoms, if any? Is there any note of treatment (prior to demigod discovery) being effective/ineffective?

Comment: Wait counselling psychologists can't treat ADHD can they? I thought ADHD is treated either by a psychiatrist or a clinical psychologist. Percy was really treated by just talking to a counselor in school? I wanted to say something like the author doesn't know ADHD but then his son has it so yeah.

Comment: @JackBauer Yes, definitely more hunter gather than farmer.

Comment: @Bellerophon Are my other questions like not answered in the books ors something?

Comment: @JackBauer Other questions?

Comment: 1 did all the demigods just stop mortal treatment for their ADHD/ADHD symptoms, if any? 2 Is there any note of treatment (prior to demigod discovery) being effective/ineffective? 3 Wait counselling psychologists can't treat ADHD can they? I thought ADHD is treated either by a psychiatrist or a clinical psychologist. 4 Percy was really treated by just talking to a counselor in school? I wanted to say something like the author doesn't know ADHD but then his son has it so yeah

Comment: @JackBauer 1 - No idea but I would assume they continue treatment in the mortal world unless they stay yea round at Camp Half-Blood. 2 - The treatment for Percy doesn't appear to have worked, presumably because this is magical ADHD rather than mortal ADHD. 3 - I have no idea how ADHD is treated. 4 - Yes, he was treated by a counsellor in school.

Answer (score 9):

According to the source novels, Percy was indeed receiving counselling for his ADHD prior to learning about his godly powers.

> I have moments like that a lot, when my brain falls asleep or
>   something, and the next thing I know I’ve missed something, as if a
>   puzzle piece fell out of the universe and left me staring at the blank
>   place behind it. **The school counsellor told me this was part of the
>   ADHD, my brain misinterpreting things.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Percy Jackson and the Lightning Thief](http://rickriordan.com/book/the-lightning-thief/)</sup></sub>

Evidently it's not uncommon for other demigods to go through the same thing,  since their abilities come across very strongly as ADHD. No counselling is offered at Camp Half-Blood and it certainly seems to be discouraged to take medication to help with the symptoms.

> ‘You don’t know anything about me.’
>   ‘No?’ She raised an eyebrow. ‘I bet you moved around from school to school. I bet you were kicked out of a lot of them.’
>   ‘How –’
>   **‘Diagnosed with dyslexia. Probably ADHD, too.’
>
>   I tried to swallow my embarrassment.** ‘What does that have to do with anything?’
>   ‘Taken together, it’s almost a sure sign. The letters float off the page when you read, right? That’s because your mind is hardwired for ancient Greek. And the ADHD – you’re impulsive, can’t sit still in the classroom. That’s your battlefield reflexes. In a real fight, they’d keep you alive. As for the attention problems, that’s because you see too much, Percy, not too little. Your senses are better than a regular mortal’s. **Of course the teachers want you medicated.** Most of them are monsters. They don’t want you seeing them for what they are.’
>   **‘You sound like… you went through the same thing?’
>
>   ‘Most of the kids here did.** If you weren’t like us, you couldn’t have survived the Minotaur, much less the ambrosia and nectar.’
>
> <sub><sup>[Percy Jackson and the Lightning Thief](http://rickriordan.com/book/the-lightning-thief/)</sup></sub>

Percy goes on to embrace this diagnosis.

> I tried to skim through Chiron’s stack of reports as we walked. There
>   were messages from demigods, nature spirits and satyrs all around the
>   country, writing about the latest monster activity. They were pretty
>   depressing, and **my ADHD brain did not like concentrating on depressing
>   stuff.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Percy Jackson and The Last Olympian](http://rickriordan.com/book/the-last-olympian/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks Valorum! Wait did I assume incorrectly? So it may be the case that Percy Jackson doesn't have ADHD but was actually misdiagnosed? In which case, Percy Jackson is not being literal when he says "my ADHD brain" because he actually means "my demigod brain which is practically an ADHD brain from the DSM-V perspective" ?

Comment: Valorum, further questions: so did all the demigods just stop mortal treatment for their ADHD/ADHD symptoms, if any? Is there any note of treatment (prior to demigod discovery) being effective/ineffective?

Comment: Wait counselling psychologists can't treat ADHD can they? I thought ADHD is treated either by a psychiatrist or a clinical psychologist. Percy was really treated by just talking to a counselor in school? I wanted to say something like the author doesn't know ADHD but then his son has it so yeah.

Answer (score 2):

It not only mentions that ADHD is something that Percy was getting help for but it also states that the reason for the ADHD in all of the demi-gods is because they are demi-gods. They are hardwired to be warriors and to read greek. Hence the reason for the dyslexia and the ADHD. This is why they are always training. Not only because of the monsters but also because it helps control the ADHD. I believe this is all explained in the first book.

Comment: Just to be clear, the training itself is the treatment for ADHD, and the treatment is effective with respect to the tasks they have to do as demigods and not necessarily with respect to other tasks such as chores or school work?

Comment: The cause for the ADHD is the survival instinct hard wired into them. So, not sure about chores and I do know that school work doesn't help with the ADHD. If school work were the answer then Percy wouldn't have had such a hard time in school especially when he was in his latin classes. But it states in the book that he could barely pass his favorite class. However Percy seems to be a natural with a sword

Comment: It's like this. ADHD causes difficulties in many areas. This could be difficulties in work as a demigod, difficulties in work as a student, difficulties in social settings or difficulties in doing household chores. My understanding of your answer is that their training at Camp Halfblood is supposed to be treatment for their ADHD. So we expect that the treatment would help them perform their jobs as demigods, but my question is if the treatment covers other aspects of their lives. Does the treatment help them with schoolwork? Does it help with social difficulties? Doing chores?

Comment: There is no adhd. It's a misdiagnoses. The doctors misdiagnose the demi-gods because they don't realize they are demi-gods. Instead what they mistake as adhd is actually a hard wired survival instinct. That's what I am trying to say.

Comment: But "Making Percy ADHD/dyslexic was my way of honoring the potential of all the kids I've known who have those conditions." ? So what RR means is "Making it *such that Percy and the demigods are misdiagnosed as* ADHD/dyslexic was..." ?

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason for Rick Riordan to add the idea of ADHD, is to complement and encourage his own son through this story. In real life, his son suffered from dyslexia and hence lagged behind in studies. So if a fictional guy with same ‘disabilities’ can be a demigod with ‘different/unique abilities’, then it would be a professional and personal gain situation. Also, as Case suggested, demigods are hard wired to learn Ancient Greek language and all godly stuff, so simple english did a juggle to them. Through this he also makes a point that every individual has unique and limited capacities. Nobody, even a god child, can know everything. If he understands ancient Latin, he won’t know basic English.

Hope this helps!